# Student's computer using Chinese locale, inherited from Windows 7

Tags: r

A student in my chemometrics course installed R on Windows 7.  Apparently, R picked up something from his computer automatically, so R operates in Chinese (yes, he is Chinese).  He's trying to change it back to English (important because scripts must be turned into me in English!).

He sent me the 1st screen shot below. The 2nd screen shot shows my suggestion to change the locale.  R reports (in Chinese) that it can't change it.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

[image: initial state]

[image: attempted change]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `sessionInfo()`

try:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")
```

Answer (score 2):

Run R with the added command line parameter `LANGUAGE=en` OR delete the share/locale folder: 
http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/412/how-to-change-language-in-r/

Comment: He's using the GUI, but the page you sent me to says there is a setting in the GUI, so he's trying that (duh on my part).

Answer (score 0):

Windows likely has a way to set the locale information passed to a program, though I don't know how offhand.  You could try setting it there, outside of R.

Comment: The R installation manual says Windows only supports one local per language, no sub-territories, but doesn't say how to change it (not surprising since R is not Windows).  But I'm a Mac guy, I don't know how these things work with R in Windows (but clearly they don't work as I thought, using an example from the help page for locales).